# Handling checkboxes in MEAN application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm very new to MEAN stack, I have been trying to save an array of check box value and try retrieving it from mongodb.I have clearly defined schema about embedded arrays using mongoose the problem is how to insert the checked items in mongodb.
my form code goes like:

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th><span>Project Name :</span></th>
    <th><input type="text" ng-model="project.projectName" placeholder="Enter projectname"></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Base Url:</th>
    <th><input type="text" ng-model="project.baseUrl" placeholder="Enter Base URL"></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Choose APIs:</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th><input type="radio" ng-model="project.api" value="downloading" ng-change="downloadAPI()"><span>Downloading API</span></th>
    <th><input type="radio" ng-model="project.api" value="scraping" ng-change="scrapAPI()"><span>Scraping API</span></th>
    <th><input type="radio" ng-model="project.api" value="comparision" ng-change="compareAPI()"><span>Comparision API</span></th>

    <tbody ng-show = "project.api=='downloading'" ng-hide="!downloading">
<tr>
    <th>Choose Files:</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th><input type="checkbox" ng-model=project.js><span>Js</span></th>
<th><input type="checkbox" ng-model=project.css> <span>Css</span></th>
<th><input type="checkbox" ng-model=project.images><span>Images</span></th>
<th><input type="checkbox" ng-model=project.fonts><span>Fonts</span></th>
<th><input type="checkbox" ng-model=project.multimedia><span>Multimedia</span></th>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tr>
    <th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="project.run" ng-change="runproject()"><span>Run as soon as project is completed!</span></th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th>
    <div ng-show="action === 'add'"><span><button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="save()">Add Project</button></span></div>
    <div ng-show="action === 'edit'"><span><button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="modify()">Update</button></span>
    </div>

    </th>
</tr>
```

Every thing is fine with the controller and my post request in the server goes like:

```
//post request
router.post('/',function(req,res,next){
 var files=[];
if(req.body.js != null){
files.push(req.body.js);
}

  if(req.body.css != null){
    files.push(req.body.css);
 }

   if(req.body.images != null){
     files.push(req.body.images);
  }

   if(req.body.fonts != null){
    files.push(req.body.fonts);
   }
   console.log(files);
   var obj= new project(req.body);// new object of the mongoose model

   obj.save(function(err,result){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
   res.json(result);
```

});
});

Is there any other way to store check boxes value in the database? I would highly appreciate your time and suggestions which really means a lot to me.

Answer (score 0):

When you are passing data from front end use that method

**ng-click="modify(project)"**

Data validation part also doing in client side.Use angular required competent for check null input.If you use that then do n't need to check data is null.

**files.push(req.body)**